# Let plugin check if taxonomy is already registered by another plugin

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

My site is using a custom taxonomy that can be associated with two different custom post types. Each post type is registered by a different plugin. It may be that only one of the plugins is active or that both are activated.

My idea was to let each plugin check if the taxonomy has already been registered and —if not— register it.

I put the following code into each plugin, but this —of course— gives me an error (Cannot redeclare register_taxonomy_my_taxonomy).

```
if ( !taxonomy_exists( 'my_taxonomy' ) ) {
    add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_my_taxonomy' );
    function register_taxonomy_my_taxonomy() {
        ...
}
```

Comment: I think is a problem of the hook, there you fired this check. The function `taxonomy_exists` is right for check if a taxonomy exist. Maybe you check to early. ON which hook was the check fired?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The check is in each plugin file and is performed before "init", so it cannot detect if the other plugins will try to register this same taxonomy. I'm not very familiar with hooks and don't know how to perform this check or if there is an overall better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function is defined whether you use it or not. What you want is the PHP function `function_exists`

```
if ( !taxonomy_exists( 'my_taxonomy' )
   && !function_exists('register_taxonomy_my_taxonomy') 
) {
    add_action( 'init', 'register_taxonomy_my_taxonomy' );
    function register_taxonomy_my_taxonomy() {
        ...
}
```

You should be able to create a reusable library (class) that would take care of this problem more elegantly, though.